# calling method from external file in express routes

Tags: express

Hi I am new to expressjs. I have an admin route where I would like admin to update record and etc. I don't want to write code to updated record under the route rather I just to pass some functions or object that fetch records from db or updated them. I am using passportjs for authenticate. Currently my route look like this -

```
app.get('/admin', function(req, res){

    res.render('admin', {
        title: "Welcome Member_name ",
        user: req.user
    });
});
```

So I have created another js file for all admin operation. its under root/controller/admin.js and its looks like this -

```
var     mysql       = require('mysql'),
    dbconfig    = require('../config/database'),
    connection  = mysql.createConnection(dbconfig.connection);

    module.exports = {


    }
```

what I am after is to write some function that will get some data from the database and return the object so that I can pass the object to my route and from there to the view. Can anyone help me plz? thanks. Also if you know best practice for learning expressjs plz let me know. Thanks a lot in advance. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to answer this one for you, although you question was a bit muddy to understand. If I'm right you'd like to call a method in your module from your route?

Let us say your module file was called `admin.js` for the following example. This is how you would create a method accessible outside of the module.

`admin.js`

```js
var mysql       = require('mysql'),
    dbconfig    = require('../config/database'),
    connection  = mysql.createConnection(dbconfig.connection);

module.exports = {};

module.exports.retrieveData = function() {
    //Data retrieval code here.
};
```

Then in your routes file, let us say `routes.js` for the example. This is how you would call the method.

`routes.js`

```js
var admin = require('./admin.js') //Remembering to require the module!

database.retrieveData();
```

You would then pass your query through a parameter in the `retrieveData()` method.

Comment: module.exports.stockData = function(){
 stockRecord = connection.query("query here", function(err, rows){
  if(err){
   throw err;
  }
  if(!rows.length){
   console.log("No record found");
  }
  else{
   return rows;
  }
 }); 
}; all I want to do is return the results to the route. apologies i am very new to expressjs.

Comment: This is what I have so far. All I want is to pass the results to the route so that I can fetch them. Plz take a look. http://codepen.io/jahhidhaque/pen/QExzgY

Comment: You will want to return rows from the `module.exports.stockData` method if there are `rows`. You'd then access this data in the stock variable in your route. Note that I also return false if rows were not found. https://jsfiddle.net/cjmjn3xa/